# Is there a way to add a dropdown menu to part of my Navbar without pushing down the rest of the content?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create a drop down menu for my "reviews" link on my navbar, and have struggled because for some reason it pushes down the content of the page by expanding the navigation bar to fit the dropdowns content. If possible, could someone help me figure out how to create a dropdown menu that I can add on-to as my website grows?
As a sidenote, could someone check my css for the header and make sure that it looks ok? I really would appreciate it!

Here is my HTML code (which I have reverted)

```css
/* Add a background color with some padding to the body */

body {
  background: #383F51;
  font-family: Geneva, sans-serif;
}

/* Header and Blog Title */

header {
  background: #91c7b1;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: "Electrolize", sans-serif;
}

header p {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 24px;
}

/* navbar/*
/* top navigation bar style */
nav {
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* navigation bar links */

nav a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: "Electrolize", sans-serif;
}
/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */
/* Left column */
.rightcolumn {
  flex: 1;
}

.leftcolumn {
  flex: 5;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
.row {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;}

main > .row {
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  main > .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/* images (work in progress at the moment) */

/* Post layout for articles and additional areas */
.post {
  display: block;
  background-color:white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #91c7b1;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
article h2, article h2 a, .post h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #533A71;
}

article h5{
  font-size: 16px;
  
}
.post p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* Footer */

footer {
  color: black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #91c7b1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Project Incredible Indie Games</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Electrolize&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>
      <!-- Begin Header -->
      <header role="banner">
        <h1>Incredible Indie Games</h1>
        <p>Reviews and Reccomendations for the Moderate Indie Gamer</p>
        <!-- End Header -->
        <!-- Begin Navigation -->
      </header>
      <nav role="navigation">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Reviews</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </nav>
      <!-- End Navigation -->
      <!-- End Header -->
      <!-- Begin Main Content -->
      <main role="main">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Begin Blog Posts -->
          <section class="leftcolumn">
            <article class="post" role="article">
              <h2> <a href="Ori-and-The-Blind-Forest.html">Ori and The Blind Forest: A Soulful and Stunning Action-Platformer</a></h2>
              <h5><time datetime="2021-09-22">Sep, 22 2021</time></h5>
              <img src="ori-and-the-blind.png" alt="Ori and The Blind Forest Game Cover">
              <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
            </article>
            <article class="post">
              <h2>Ori and The Will of the Wisps</h2>
              <h5>Sep 23, 2021</h5>
              <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
            </article>
          </section>
          <!-- End Blog Posts -->
          <!-- Begin Sidebar -->
          <aside class="rightcolumn" role="complementary">
            <section class="post">
              <h2>About Me</h2>
              <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
              </section>
             <section class="post">
             <h2>Upcoming Posts</h2>
             </section>
          </aside>
          <!--End Sidebar -->
        </div>
      </main>
      <!--End Main -->
      <!--Begin Footer-->
      <footer class="footer" role="contentinfo">
      <p>Blog Created by: Abby Lake</p>
      </footer>
      <!--End Footer-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in codepen, but unable to see any dropdown.
Anyway,here is a simple tutorial to help you: [Dropdown tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kctqguvf2FM)

Also, your header css looks okay. Some Css tips: try to use 'rem' units as far as possible, avoid using overly complex css selectors to avoid specificity issues.

Comment: I appreciate your link, and note that this is the code without a navbar. When I tried the navigation dropdown from those sort of websites, it would overlay my website and so I removed it. I was looking for code samples of what a non-obstrived navigation dropdown would be, but thank you for your contribution.